# How to upload document to only 1 site

Tags: powershell, document

How can I upload documents only to one site and not all sites?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item "C:\DP")).GetFiles(); 
$templateFolder = "content web parts";
foreach($site in Get-SPSite) {
   $web = $site.OpenWeb();
$folder = $web.GetFolder("_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/" + $templateFolder);
foreach($file in $files)
{   
    $stream = $file.OpenRead();
    $spfile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, $stream, $true);
    $stream.Close();
}

$web.Close();
$web.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item "C:\DP")).GetFiles(); 
$templateFolder = "content web parts";
$site = Get-SPSite http://siteurl
$web = $site.OpenWeb();
$folder = $web.GetFolder("_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/" + $templateFolder);
foreach($file in $files)
{   
$stream = $file.OpenRead();
$spfile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" +     $file.Name, $stream, $true);
$stream.Close();
}
$web.Close();
$web.Dispose();
```